# Вернуть метод Main к void, но сохранить работоспособность кода

Tags: c#, асинхронность, webclient

Есть такой код:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await DownloadAsync();
    }

    static async Task DownloadAsync()
    {
        var options = new ProgressBarOptions
        {
            ProgressCharacter = '─',
            ProgressBarOnBottom = true
        };
        const int totalTicks = 100;
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
        {
            var pbar = new ProgressBar(totalTicks, "Initial message", options);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) => { pbar.Tick(e.ProgressPercentage,"Download XML Plugin..."); };
            await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://dev.osel.pp.ua/Consulo/Plugins/com.intellij.xml_2961.zip"),"/home/ketronix/xml.tar.gz");
        };
    }
}
```

И лично мне кажется, что то, что метод `Main` имеет тип `Task`, не есть хорошо. Как сделать так, чтобы он был `void` и, при этом, при вызове метода загрузки файле, в отдельном потоке рисовался прогресс бар и синхронизировался с прогрессом загрузки? По сути нужно просто как-то сделать вместо `Task` - `void`, и при этом сохранить работоспособность.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: "И лично мне кажется что то что метод Main имеет тип Task не есть хорошо". Вам кажется, в этом нет ничего плохого, а вот если вы асинхронную по своей природе задачу начнете заворачивать во что-то синхронное просто ради типа возврата Main, до которого никому, кроме среды выполнения, нет дела - вот это будет "не есть хорошо".

Comment: У вас какая задача? **Дождаться**, пока файл загрузится. Значит, нужен **await** DownloadFileTaskAsync. У среды выполнения какая задача? **Дождаться**, пока программа завершится. Далее понятно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Асинхронный `Main` это как раз синтаксический сахар, который призван сократить рутину и упростить код. В вашем случае нет никакого смысла в том, чтобы "вернуть void".

Конструкция

```
static async Task Main() { ... }
```

[превращается](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main#detailed-design) компилятором в

```
private static void $GeneratedMain() =>
    Main().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```